# How to parallellize an adaptive time stepper with Dask

Tags: dask, numerical-integration

I am wondering if it's possible to parallelize an adaptive time stepper, say Runge-Kutta 23 method (or higher order) with Dask?

Say if I have 10 Dask workers (each with 1 core/rank), and I assign 10 grid points for each worker to time integrate (for a total of 100 grid points). At the first time step, all workers are given a fixed time step size `dt0`, and then each worker has to compute the differences of RK2 and RK3 methods for its 10 grid points, **somehow** sending this info to another worker/core/rank, and this 11th worker will compute the total error of all 100 grid points and based on which to adjust the time step size for the next time step, then the 11th worker would broadcast this new time step size `dt1` to all the rest of the workers, so all 100 grid points are always integrated at the same time values.

I can see this being a viable workflow. The only thing I am not certain, and so far haven't been able to find an example on is how to handle the communications with the 11th worker which adjusts the time step sizes. For example, how can I send result from one worker to another, and how can I pause a worker until it receives certain data from another worker?

Any hints or pointers here would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Dask's futures API might be appropriate for what you want to do. Here is an old example of adapting an optimization algorithm: https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/04/19/dask-glm-2 . The point is, you can have the client wait on a bunch of futures' result, and make a decision on what futures to submit for the next batch. This waiting can also happen in a worker, since you can submit futures from futures, and there are other synchronization primitives like Variables to keep track of state.